# Minimize html links when does not fit in screen

Tags: html, css

I have web page with multiple hyperlinks. These hyperlinks are loaded from database so can be many of them (multiple pages). My problem - i need to keep top green ribbon in same height. But currently if all elements not fit to screen they line up and that makes my green ribbon quite big.

Code: [HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/34xL95fw)
`

```
<body>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul class="active">
        <li class="current-item"><a href="?action=?home">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong class="fa-home-1x home-text">Home</strong></a></li><li><a href="?action=?t"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong class="a-sign-language-1x sign-language-text">Click 1</strong></a></li><li><a href="?action=?m"><i class="fa fa-truck fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong class="a-sign-language-1x sign-language-text">Click 2</strong></a></li><li><a href="?action=?g"><i class="fa fa-sign-language fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong class="a-sign-language-1x sign-language-text">Click 3</strong></a></li>  
        <li>
            <a href="?action=?log-out"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <strong class="fa-home-1x sign-out-text">Sign Out</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="toggle-nav" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</nav>
 </body>
```

`

Would it be possible to create something like little triangle and move those links (just overflowed) in? Or any ideas how to keep those in one line (but not with scroll)?

Comment: _"Would it be possible to create something like little triangle and move those links (just overflowed) in?"_ - this is known as [Priority+ Navigation Pattern](https://css-tricks.com/the-priority-navigation-pattern/) ... should be able to find applicable scripts yourself using that as keyword.

Comment: There are many options: shrink the margin of the `li` elements, make the font smaller on smaller displays or hide some/all elements in a hamburger menu when the display width is very small.

Comment: Why can't you add media query to your nav.. ?

Comment: @CBroe now i know what i'm looking for. Thanks

Comment: @ManushVenkatesh because with media query need to be fixed parameter . But if dynamic elements then i don't think you can do it

Comment: This is not possible with out  some sort of scroll functionality, because of maths.